# LEFT JOIN on a nullable column. What is the behaviour?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, relational-algebra

It is not clear to me what is the behaviour of a LEFT JOIN if you try to JOIN on a column that may be NULL.
E.g.

```
SELECT columns  
FROM  
EmployeePayment ep JOIN EmployeePaymentGroup g ON g.group_id = ep.group_id  AND g.subsidiary_id = ep.subsidiary_id  
LEFT JOIN EmployeeSalaryDetails esd USING (department_id)    
LEFT JOIN Employee e ON e.id = esd.emp_id
```

What happens if the ***INNER JOIN of EmployeePayment and EmployeePaymentGroup return 1 record*** and then the second ***LEFT JOIN on EmployeeSalaryDetails retains this record*** but this record has as esd.emp_id a NULL value and try to LEFT JOIN on Employee on that NULL value.
I know that NULLs are tricky so I was wondering how does the LEFT JOIN cope with NULLs

**Note:**
I opened a question earlier about JOINs but the comment of Abhik Chakraborty make me realise that there was a problem with a NULL value in a condition

Comment: @fancyPants:I actually tried it and the record is retained despite the fact of the NULLness. But since I know NULLs are tricky I don't want to end up with some surprise later e.g. weird/undefined behavior

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `LEFT JOIN` and the right table returns nothing (`NULL`) all the fields belonging to the right table in the projection are simply `NULL`, but you still get your result from the left table. `RIGHT JOIN` has the opposite behavior and `INNER JOIN` will not return anything.

```
SELECT * FROM `left_table` LEFT JOIN `right_table`
```

`NULL = NULL` evaluates to `UNKNOWN` (which means “no, don’t join because I have no clue if we are allowed to.”) and the projection will only contain the results from the left table.

Of course there are ways to go around this problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM `left_table` AS `l`
    LEFT JOIN `right_table` AS `r`
        ON `r`.`id` <=> `l`.`id`
```

Now checks against `NULL` will work normally as you are used to (`NULL <=> NULL` is `1` and `'value' <=> NULL` is `0`). Also see the documentation for the [equal to](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) operator.

Comment: But what if you do a left join on columns that are NULL in **both** tables?

Comment: `NULL = NULL` evaluates to `FALSE` and you'll only get the result from the left table.

Comment: Nit: `NULL = NULL` neither evaluates to `TRUE` nor to `FALSE`. It doesn't matter here (since for join conditions, it only matters whether the condition is true, or something else), but it does matter in general, because `NOT (NULL = NULL)` is *not* `NOT FALSE`.

Comment: It wasn't meant like that, I wanted to express that it evaluates to `FALSE` regarding the join condition ("shall I join?" answer "no"). Of course you're right with your comment. We'd have to use `field IS NOT NULL` to get a real evaluation as we want it.

Comment: `NULL = NULL` actualy evaluates to `UNKNOWN`, not `FALSE`. The result is the same though, you get only the result from the left table.

Comment: I extended my answer further to make things more clear. Thanks for your comments guys.

Answer (score -1):

You can use isnull(cast()) function to convert the null record in a type and give it a value that is also in the employee column in order to join them based on that value.

```
LEFT JOIN EmployeeSalaryDetails esd on isnull((esd.department_id, "input here value of id") =  "input here the value of the column"
```

**Here is a example:**

```
Inner join FORECAST_Claims b on  (isnull(cast(a.Durg_Key as varchar(20)),'UNKNOWN') = isnull(cast(b.Durg_Key as varchar(20)),'UNKNOWN')
```

Comment: Can you give an example in a query?

Comment: LEFT JOIN EmployeeSalaryDetails esd on isnull((esd.department_id, "input here value of id") =  "input here the value of the column"

Comment: `"input here value of id"`? What id? I don't have an id.

Comment: From my second query, 'Unknown' represents the value you want to give to the a.Durg_Key column in case it is null.